# how to Convert pdf file to image file and viceversa

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, vba

In my appliation I want to convert a PDF file to an image and then an image file to a PDF.

Is there any free SDK available to implement this one..?

I already used PDFSharp, but it's not free. Is there any one knows about free SDK..?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177/how-do-i-programmatically-create-a-pdf-in-my-net-application

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like PDFCreator - http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfcreator/

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ghostscript? It is a command line tool which can be called from your application:
http://www.ghostscript.com/

Answer (score 0):

How about PDF Sharp itself? Since [it is free](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=29&Itemid=43), actually! (Looks like 3 clause BSD.)

You can pay for support if you wish, but there is no obligation to do so.